# How to get rid of dictionary number when dynamically building on

Tags: python, dictionary

```
device_total={}
user_n="Cisco"
pwd= "test"
count=1
for i in range(0,31):
    ip_addr= input('Please enter the device IP address' + ' : ')
    dev_type = input (" Enter device type" + ' : ')
    dsum = {'device type':dev_type,'host':ip_addr,'username':user_n,'password':pwd}
    device_total[i] = dsum
    i+1
    query_user=input('Do you want to add additional devices? (y/n)' )
    if query_user != 'y':
       break
print(device_total)
```

I am trying to dynamically create multiple dictionaries based on a user input to be used to configure network devices with Netmiko, the dictionaries are built but every one of them is numbered which causes a line error when the Netmiko functions are trying to use them to log in a make configuration changes. Please let me know if there is a way to create the dictionary without them. I would like to create a separate dictionary for each device entered by the user not one with multiple entries. Thanks.

See example below:

```
{0: {'device type': 'cisco', 'host': '1.1.1.1', 'username': 'Cisco', 'password': 'test'}, 1: {'device type': 'Arista', 'host': '2.2.2.2', 'username': 'Cisco', 'password': 'test'}}
```

Comment: I suspect you do not want a dictionary at all, but a list.  I suggest `device_total=[]`, and then `device_total.append( dsum )` insteaed of `device_total[i] = dsum`.

Comment: Thank you, but I do need a dictionary. The title was wrong for my question was wrong , I am trying to split the dictionaries once they are nested. I have been looking for a solution on the web, and it looks like no one has ever encountered this issue.

Comment: Since you haven't shown us how you will USE this info, there's little we can do.  Note that `device_total.values() ` will return all the values without their keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with for anyone else that may in the same situation and stuck.

```
from getpass import getpass
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from netmiko import NetmikoAuthenticationException


def user_input():
    """ Getting user credentials """
    usr_n = input("username: ")
    pwd = getpass()
    cred = (usr_n, pwd)

    return cred


def net_devices():
    login_info = user_input()
    username = login_info[0]
    password = login_info[1]

    with open("districts devices.txt") as f:

        net_devices = f.read().splitlines()

    for device in net_devices:
        try:
            netw_devices = {"device_type": 'cisco_ios', 'host': device, 'username': username, 'password': password}
            net_connect = ConnectHandler(**netw_devices)
        except NetmikoAuthenticationException:
            print(f"Unable to login to {device}. Verify you have the right credentials or it is added to ISE.")
            continue

        """ Verifying the access-list has been applied to the device. """

        print('Verifying ACL the is on: ' + device)

        verification = net_connect.send_command('show run | b line vty')

        if "access-class" not in verification:
            print("\nThe access-class is missing from this device's configuration. Configuring the ACL on: "
                  + device)
            acl_cmds = ['service password-encryption', 'ip access-list standard Sample-ONLY',
                        'permit 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255',
                        ' permit 172.16.0.0 0.0.255.255', 'line vty 0 15', 'transport in ssh',
                        'access-class sample in', 'do write memory']
            commands = net_connect.send_config_set(acl_cmds)
            print(commands)
            


        else:
            print("\nNo update necessary.\n")

            # print(" \nVerifying the ACL is now in place.")
            # re_verification = net_connect.send_command('\nshow run | b line vty')
            # print(re_verification)

            net_connect.disconnect()


net_devices()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
device_total=[]
user_n="Cisco"
pwd= "test"
count=1
for i in range(0,31):
    ip_addr= input('Please enter the device IP address' + ' : ')
    dev_type = input (" Enter device type" + ' : ')
    dsum = {'device type':dev_type,'host':ip_addr,'username':user_n,'password':pwd}
    device_total.append( dsum)
    i+1
    query_user=input('Do you want to add additional devices? (y/n)' )
    if query_user != 'y':
       break
print(device_total)
```